# How to auto trim parameter before insert/select/update to Database with IDE mybatis

Tags: java, oracle, mybatis

I'm using `mybatis` to connect to a database. I want to `trim` all parameters before calling the commands `insert`/`select`/`update` for the database.
How do I do it with `mybatis` and Java?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve]. Have you looked at `String#trim`?

Comment: Please read my question carefully. I asked "auto trim", not "manual trim"

Comment: I read your question, "auto" and "manual" are pretty ambiguous terms when it comes to programming. For instance when you say "manual trim", I think you're referring to actually trimming each parameter by hand, like in Notepad, not that that makes any sense. Could you please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] (or what you're code currently looks like), to add more details to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Check [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31161274/7076047) to a similar question (changing values). String type handler is overridden to replace NULL with empty String.

In  your case, override the *setNonNullParameter* method to set the trimmed value instead of original value.

Type handlers are applied globally, it will then feels "automatic".

Answer (score -1):

mybatis trim

```
select ** ,** ,** from *** where time(**) = #{params}
```